# 2005 sebring overheating

Tags: overheating, sebring

My 2005 sebring is over heating , there is no sign of water in oil,but a little milky film in the coolant reservoir . What are the possible causes. we let the car run at idle about 15 min to get the cooling fans to kick on , the engine is one of the quietest I've heard

Answer (score 2):

The milky film is likely to be oil in the water. I'd say Head Gasket - a recognized problem on Sebrings, usually at around the 100,000 mile mark. On a Sebring, that's quite an expensive little job unless you can do the work yourself.

Comment: Head gasket blows after 100k without being overheated? Wow, these engines are garbage.

Comment: This one is overheating, but yes - Repairpal.com has reports of it. To the OP - I'd spend a little money at a garage confirming that it's the head gasket, as it can be a $2K job at a garage to fix. Or, you could use the  liquid sealers that they sell in the car stores, and change a 'head gasket replacement' into a 'head gasket replacement, radiator replacement, heater core replacement, and thorough flush'.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Chrysler motors in general suffer from bad engineering.